# weekend is not saturday/sunday

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/weekends/

I am very new to this library. I want to NOT display the weekends, but I have a big problem. my weekend is friday/saturdy.

how can I fix the default weekend days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `weekends: false` you can use the [`hiddenDays` option](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/hiddenDays/):

```
hiddenDays: [5, 6]
```